# Pods Structure in Ember Addon

Tags: ember.js, ember-addon

With respect to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55136664/combining-two-emberjs-apps) question, I created an ember-addon project and it is working fine as expected.

But If I try to introduce pods structure in the ember-addon project it is not working.

It throws error that the `route is not found`.
What should I do?

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: do you know which route isn't found?

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli the route from the addon is not found in the consuming app

Comment: You'll need to use blueprints to add the routes to the parent app's router.  If I understand it right,  ember-engines solves this in a different way.

For blueprints use afterInstall hook and this.insertIntoFile into the 'app/router.js' to insert the routes as big js string.

Comment: Here is an example from my OSS project: https://github.com/yahoo/navi/blob/master/packages/reports/blueprints/navi/index.js

Comment: @freakydavid Did you had a look at this StackOverflow question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39013075/add-route-to-ember-addon The accepted answer works fine even in latest ember versions.

Comment: @jelhan I found the answer...Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help....My issue was that if I try to use pods structure in ember addon,It won't compile the template files.This is an existing issue in ember-cli.

With reference to [issue](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/5406)
in the github...they have provided the workarounds possible for lower version of ember

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned](https://cli.emberjs.com/release/advanced-use/project-layouts/) in the official docs, addons **should not** use the `pods` structure:

> Addons **should only use** the classic structure for compatibility
> with either classic or pods-based consuming application.